# remove additional space before `:`

Tags: math-mode, symbols

In this math code:

```
\exists^\omega n : \alpha [0,n] \notin A
```

it adds some empty space before and after `:`.

I want to avoid/remove the space before it. How?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `\colon` instead of `:`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
$\exists^\omega n \mathalpha{:\,} \alpha [0,n] \notin A$
```