# One symbol like \omegaup

Tags: symbols

Please see the below image, what is the TeX code for the left most symbol? It is like `\omegaup`, but looked thinner and a little italic. I have looked it through the file `symbols-a4.pdf` and didn't find it. If it is really in the file, please point it out and forgive my careless.

[image: one symbol like omegaup]

Comment: I agree with TH. It would help if you knew the name of the symbol.

Comment: @TH: according to your comment, i tried `italic w`. yes, it is really like what it is in the Chinese Load Standard. i am really stupid. thank you.

Comment: @Andrey: the symbol is used for chinese civil engineer to calculate wind load according to relative chinese standard. it has a specific physical meaning but i don't know how to give it an english name. i am sorry.

Comment: @TH: Maybe you make an answer out of your comment so that this question won't stay "unanswered".

Comment: @TH: See, it already gave you 80 rep `:-)` The simplest answers seem to be most appreciated ...

Comment: @Hendrik: Not that I was hurting for rep, but it is amusing to compare it to some of my lengthier answers.

Comment: @TH: Exactly what I meant. When I was posting [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13638/remove-additional-space-before/13647#13647), I also was a bit surprised at the outcome.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like a *w* to me.