# Reduce spacing around colons in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I'm working on math. Here I want to reduce the spacing around the colon (':'). By default spaces are inserted before and after the colon. Could you please advise me as to how this could be rectified?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$
DE:AB = 18:6 \quad AB:12 = CE:15
$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: If `AB` etc are not products of two variables but a single quantity referred to by two letters, you may want to consider `\mathit{AB}`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6087/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129400/35864

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Use \colon instead of :.
credit: [Hendrik Vogt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13647/201340)

Comment: Use \colon instead of :.
credit: [Hendrik Vogt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13647/201340)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can redeclare `:` to be of class `\mathord`.  If have to restore the original behaviour, use `\mathrel{:}`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathord}{operators}{"3A}

\begin{document}

\[ DE:AB = 18:6 \quad AB:12 = CE:15 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I’d go for a different name, _e.g._, `\DeclareMathSymbol{\dv}{\mathord}{operators}{"3A}`.  I’d also consider `\DeclareMathSymbol{\dv}{\mathbin}{operators}{"3A}`.

Comment: @GuM See updated answer.  I don't think you have to wrap it in a command.  After all you want the spacing around colon to be consistent throughout.  But it's good to know how to go back, which I have added to my answer.

Comment: @GuM After seeing the output, I’d go for something like `\newcommand\dv{\,{:}\,}`

Comment: @egreg: I cannot make up my mind for either of the two variants (thin space or medium space).  Perhaps a matter of personal taste.  Maybe `\newcommand*\dv{\noscript\,{:}\noscript\,}` (or a robustified version thereof)?

Comment: Hi Henri thanks for your suggestion it has helpful and working fine.

Answer (score 20):

You're using the colon as an operation symbol, which is seldom done in professional mathematics, where the colon usually denotes a relation symbol. However, the colon is commonly found in elementary mathematics.

Here is a visual comparison:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
& DE:AB = 18:6                     && \text{too wide} \\
& DE{:}AB = 18{:}6                 && \text{too tight} \\
& DE{\,:\,}AB = 18{\,:\,}6         && \text{maybe better} \\
& DE\mathbin{:}AB = 18\mathbin{:}6 && \text{right, IMO} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When you have decided what's best for you, add one of the following definitions (`\rt` is for ‘ratio’, choose a different name if you wish):

```
\newcommand{\rt}{{:}}         % for choice 2
\newcommand{\rt}{{\,:\,}}     % for choice 3
\newcommand{\rt}{\mathbin{:}} % for choice 4
```

and input your proportions as

```
DE \rt AB = 18 \rt 6
```

Answer (score 11):

Just put the colons in groups.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
DE{:}AB = 18{:}6 \quad AB{:}12 = CE{:}15
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose a command that seems cleaner in my opinion, and that lets you postpone the decision (in case you want to fine tune the output in the future)

```
\newcommand*\ratio[1]{\cleanratio#1\relax}
\def\cleanratio#1:#2\relax{#1\mathbin{:}#2}
```

and then use `\ratio{DE:AB} = \ratio{18:6} = \ratio{3:1}`. That way if you want to change the output you can (for instance `#1\,\mathord{:}\,#2`, or whatever). If you prefer a cleaner syntax like `\ratio DE:AB = \ratio 18:6 = \ratio 3:1` we can implement it.